# How to move on from Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, turbo-c++

In my school, they only teach on Tubro C++. I can program well in the DosBox but I want to develop my own applications, algorithms, etc. The problem is that I don't know where to start. The spectrum is so broad, I don't know what gcc or g++ are other than the fact that they are compilers.
I don't know how to use VS Code (mac) to compile & run. I don't know anything about the modern C++.
**Where should I start?**

I wanna do Machine Learning related stuff and GUI.
I actually have a browser based application in mind where I'd be needing Artificial Intelligence, cool GUI, etc.

Comment: Seems clear-cut to me. Do research on gcc or g++ if you want to work out what they are. Look at tutorials on using VS Code to work out how to compile and run. Read a book about C++.

Comment: The Internet is freedom! There are so many tutorials out there... Just put the work on it!

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/05-installing-an-integrated-development-environment-ide/ this might help

Comment: Technically, implementing algorithms is possible with TurboC++. But you're indeed better off with something recent - many algorithms and building blocks for algorithms are now available in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very good question. I think these steps would be the easiest for you -

1. Install Linux on your laptop or use macOS. I say this because you can develop in windows but it would be much easier on Linux or a mac because of the sheer size of the community.
2. Get familiar with the command line on Linux/macOS. You should try on [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) which is one of the most popular versions of Linux. You must be able to use commands like - `ls`, `cd`, `pwd`. You can find lots of content for this easily.
3. Get familiar with the `vim` text editor.
4. After writing your first `HelloWorld` program on C++ using vim, you should learn how to use the g++ command to compile and run your code.
5. After you are familiar with all of the above, to make your work easier you can download and use text editors like [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

These were my initial steps in the world of programming. I would also recommend you create an account on [Github](https://github.com/) and browse other open source community projects, also learn `git`. Lastly explore also other domains and languages like web development, machine learning, python etc. Otherwise, if you are into competitive coding, C++ is indeed an excellent choice. For this, you can visit platforms like [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/), [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com), [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) etc.

For tutorials, you can find many sites like [Udacity](https://in.udacity.com/), [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), [edX](https://www.edx.org/). [MIT OCW](https://www.youtube.com/user/MIT) is a popular resource on YouTube for formal courses like Algorithms and Data Structures.

PS. Do not waste your time learning everything about everything. Instead, you should keep on experimenting and look up on the web whenever some error or a bug pops up.

Comment: A lot of people suggest using IDE, instead of Command Line, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @AlphaMineron It is always upto you. I prefer text editors because nowadays they come with many features like error check etc. New features can be installed as and when required. If you use the debugger heavily then you may use an IDE.

Comment: @AlphaMineron I am guessing you are new to the software world. Therefore I will suggest you use the command line. It will teach you the basics and the internal processes which happen. You can always learn an IDE easily once you feel you need advanced features.

Comment: Oh yea I am! I'm just a High School student. I was interested in GUI development thatswhy I tried using Qt Creator, although I do know a bit of git (I use bitbucket) and I love using command line for it. I asked another question relating that, so if you wish to check it out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218316/how-to-get-started-with-ides-especially-qt-creator)

Answer (score 0):

Since TurboC++ was just a compiler, maybe you'd be happiest just moving into a full blown IDE(Integrated Development Environment)!

For Mac, I might recommend Eclipse. It's a very popular IDE and can be used for C++.

However, you'll need a compiler. GCC is a good compiler for Mac, but as far as I know you need Apple's "XCode" IDE to install GCC in the first place. So if you were to go through all of that effort you may just want to stick with XCode.

You'd need an Apple Developer login, but here's a tutorial on getting GCC up and running.

https://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/

Of course, nothing is keeping you from sleeping around with some new languages, but if you want to stick to C++ I'd say get your compiler, find an IDE you like and get to learning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know How compiler works and the program structure.

I recomend you an excelent course called  "**Programming Paradigms**", from Stanford University. You can find it in ITunes University and it is free.