# How to get started with IDEs, Especially Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm a highschool student, who have only ever coded in Turbo C++. I have no idea how IDEs work, I installed Qt Creator to start learning GUI programming but I can't even get it to run a simple C++ code. I doesn't know what files to include.
NOTE: **I'm a total newbie**.
The tutorials I found on YT are confusing and not clear. I have no idea why this is happening. This is my code:

```
#include<IOSTREAM.H>
#include<CONIO.H>

void main() {
    clrscr();
    cout << "Hello World!";
    getch();
}
```

I did build all, then run but I got this Issue:

> No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.

Screenshot of Qt Creator

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error messages as well ?

Comment: The No rule to make target 'all'. Stop. is what came out in the Issues window in the bottom

Comment: I am not much familiar with qt. But a Qt program is not same as your turbo c++ program. First get familiar with c++ 14. You don't use clrscr on non windows machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `clrscr()` is Windows specific (or is it Turbo C++ specific - I forget), in any case; don't use it.
2. `cout` should be `std::cout`.
3. you should include "iostream" not those obsolete ".h" versions (besides, the header names are lowercase, not uppercase).
4. `void main` is not valid. `main` *always* returns `int`.

Note: these bugs have *nothing* to do with Qt nor qtcreator. They are just, plain and simple, bugs in your code. Read Qt documentation and try out some tutorials.

Comment: In addition, he does not have a project, he has just opened a .pro file, he must create the .pro file.

Comment: @eyllanesc No, I did create the project as plain c++ applications.

Comment: @Jesper Wait, those are the bugs due to me using TurboC++ type code in place of C++11. Are you sure the: _"No rule to make target `all'. Stop."_ is due to that? I think its because of missing executable file. I'm confused as compiling in TurboC++ automatically made all the req. files and I could simply press "RUN".

Comment: I never said "No rule to make target `all'. Stop." Was due to that. I was simply pointing out obvious bugs in your code. But you could start by fixing the obvious errors and then see if the problem persists - that would be a pretty normal and reasonable approach.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, It turns out that the project was never created. I was working on a existing project which was modified by Qt but the makefile was never included, thus the error.